# How to remove a observer with name .ALAssetsLibraryChanged in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm converting an video editor app to swift 3 from 2.3 and I have an issue at `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver` at the parameter `name: NSNotification.Name.ALAssetsLibraryChanged` was depricated in iOS 9.0. I have modified it as in worning to `NSNotification.Name.photoLibraryDidChanged` and now ot gives me the error:

> Type `NSNotification.Name` has no member `photoLibraryDidChanged`

Here's the full code line:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.photoLibraryDidChanged, object: photoLibary)
```

Comment: As of iOS 8 you should be using `PHPhotoLibrary` instead of `ALAssetsLibrary`

Comment: Yes, but as I'm new to swift, I'm still hard reading the documentations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this issue by using this:

`NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "photoLibraryDidChanged"), object: photoLibary)`

instad of this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.photoLibraryDidChanged, object: photoLibary)
```

Comment: If you are trying to remove an observer then you must have added the observer. What notification are you using when you add the observer? You need to use the same value when you remove the observer. The code in this answer is very unlikely to actually work. It may compile but it won't actually do what you want.